# Why is This Minipage Footnote Repeated Twice?

Tags: errors, footnotes, minipage

Consider:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{scalefnt,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\begin{minipage}{5.0in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
{\vstretch{1.05}{\huge{\scalefont{1.05}{\textbf{THE COMMONITORY}}}\footnote{{\scshape{Commonitory.}} I have retained the original title in its anglicised form, already familiar to English ears in connection with the name of Vincentius. Its meaning, as he uses it, is indicated sufficiently, in \S 3, ``An aid to memory.'' Technically, it meant a Paper of Instructions given to a person charged with a commission, to assist his memory as to its details.}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

QUESTION: Why is the only footnote listed *three* times? Also, how may I get the one footnote listed once at the bottom of the page (instead of directly underneath the title) and with a footnotemark of 1 instead of *a*?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the scalerel package and the `\vstretch`. Normal behavior of minipage is to put the footnote text UNDER the minipage and not at the end of the page. Scarerel puts its arguments in a box hence footnote is expanded, then expanded again when processed. You have overcomplicated the code IMHO.

Comment: @yannisl Thank you, that works.

Comment: @yannisl IMHO your comment already explains the cause of the problem good enough to be an acceptable answer. (It would be perfect, if you'd add also the resulting code into a real answer, but IMHO this would be optional).

Comment: @cabohah Thanks. Will you please if you can post it, as I am out of action for the rest of the day?

Comment: @yannisl My problem is, that I cannot reproduce the issue. Even if I correct the `(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)` mistake, I do not get a repeated footnote, neither with up-to-date TeX Live nor with a very older TeX Live 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I cannot reproduce your problem. With your code, I get:

[image: original result]

and in the `log` a warning:

> ```
> (\end occurred inside a group at level 1)
>
> ### simple group (level 1) entered at line 5 ({)
> ```

This is because the `{` a the beginning of line 5 is never closed.

However, there are several more issues with your code. It seems you are trying to use `\huge` as command with argument. But this isn't correct. `\huge` is a font switch. It does not read an argument, but ends at the end of the current group (in your case the end of the box used by `\vstretch`).

I also guess, that you are using the `\vstretch` only because of a missing end of paragraph after using `\huge`. So IMHO the `\vstretch` can be eliminated too. In this case the `\huge` would end at the group started by the `{` currently before the `\vstretch`. This group is also not needed, but would end the baselineskip setting of `\huge`.

The `minipage` is also relevant for the position of the output of the footnote. Footnotes inside `minipage` are always printed at the end of the `minipage` not the end of the page. And to make this more clear, the number style is changed.

So IMHO you would get, what you want with simplified code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering\huge\textbf{THE COMMONITORY\footnote{{\scshape{Commonitory.}} I
      have retained the original title in its anglicised form, already
      familiar to English ears in connection with the name of Vincentius. Its
      meaning, as he uses it, is indicated sufficiently, in \S 3, ``An aid to
      memory.'' Technically, it meant a Paper of Instructions given to a
      person charged with a commission, to assist his memory as to its
      details.}}\par}

\end{document}
```

Note the `\par` at the end of the group. It is needed to use all the font settings of `\huge` (including the baselineskip) for the huge text.

[image: improved]

If you really want to stretch the text, use something like:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{scalerel,scalefnt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering\huge\vstretch{1.05}{\textbf{\scalefont{1.05}{THE COMMONITORY\footnotemark}}}\footnotetext{\textsc{Commonitory.} I
      have retained the original title in its anglicised form, already
      familiar to English ears in connection with the name of Vincentius. Its
      meaning, as he uses it, is indicated sufficiently, in \S 3, ``An aid to
      memory.'' Technically, it meant a Paper of Instructions given to a
      person charged with a commission, to assist his memory as to its
      details.}\par}

\end{document}
```

BTW: If this should not be a one-time formatting but a kind of sectioning, you should use a package like `titlesec` to configure the corresponding sectioning command, e.g., `\chapter`, instead of doing manual markup for each heading.